# ImageBundle - Unable to find image resource problem

Tags: gwt

Hi I'm trying to implement a ImageBundle for my gwt app.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public interface MenuImageBundle extends ImageBundle {
    @Resource("icons/001_15.png")
    AbstractImagePrototype fileNewIcon();
}
```

But I get this error when the gwt app calls for the fileNewIcon():

```
Unable to find image resource 'icons/001_15.png'
```

Although the icon image is in the icons folder in the WAR folder.

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`icons` package should be in your classpath. Look [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ImageBundle.html) for more information.